# Why most_similar in word2vec doesn't consider the term itself?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, similarity

I am working on a entity similarity project. The `most_similar` in word2vec gensim model works fine in this regard. However, I also want the search term itself to be included in the outcome. It should be something like this:

```
>>> model = Word2Vec(sw_token, min_count=2)
>>> model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load("model.bin")
>>> model.wv.most_similar("melanoma", topn=5)

[('melanoma', 1.000000),
 ('cutaneous', 0.6512814164161682),
 ('uveal', 0.6295092701911926),
 ('gp100', 0.617050290107727),
 ('ligand-bearing', 0.614188551902771)]
```

The official documents doesn't shows anything which can help me here. Also, if there are terms such as `melanoma xyz` how can we get such a word as closer in most_similar? I understand that it will take word into account so two words count as 2 not one therefore, they are not similar here. maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it behaves the way it does is that your preferred behavior is not a common preference: most users supplying a single word as the origin point don't need that same word repeated as the top result. Of *course* the word itself is the closest to itself, and has a cosine-similarity of `1.0`. (Similarly, when using this method in the mode useful for analogy-solving – `model.most_similar(positive=['queen', 'man'], negative=['king']]` – none of the supplied words are wanted in the candidate answers.)

As [Itamar Trainnin's answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64810246/130288), if you need that for some reason, you can prepend that axiomatic result yourself.

Note also that if you supply raw vectors as the origin, rather than a key word to lookup for the origin, no filtering of results based on supplied keys happens. So the following will include `'melanoma'` among the results:

```
model.wv.most_similar(positive=[model.wv['melanoma']], topn=5)
```

It's not clear what you mean by "if there are terms such as `melanoma xyz` how can we get such a word as closer in most_similar". It is possible to have trained your model with the word `'melanoma xyz'`. (If that was supplied as a word-token in sufficient numbers during model creation & training, a word-vector will be learned for that token. And that token will be returned, when it's among the top results for a `most_similar()` query.

But if the model wasn't trained with such a token, it won't have any vector for that string, and thus `'melanoma xyz'` can't be a returned result. (And, if provided as an origin, would create a `KeyError`.)

If `'melanoma xyz'` is a distinct concept in your domain, that you would like to be treated as its own word (& get its own word-vector), you could consider changing your initial tokenization to retain it as a unit, rather than break it up into `['melanoma', 'xyz']`. That might be accomplished by some hand-picked list of word-groupings to combine, or by using a statistical analysis like that offered by the [Gensim `Phrases` class](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_3.8.3/models/phrases.html). (It's most typical to use an explicit underscore `'_'` to re-group such tokens into single tokens, for clarity.) After training on such text, `'melanoma_xyz'` would have word-vector & thus receive a learned-vector.

If you don't have the option of such explicit multiword-combinations at the start, you could also consider:

1. When you have a string like `'melanoma xyz'` as a query, split it into two words – `['melanoma', 'xyz']` – and create a single vector of the average of both those words (if both are independently present in your model). This is crude but may be better than nothing.
2. Consider using a model like `FastText` - which does a supercharged version of (1) where every fragment of any word contributes somewhat to its word-vector. Thus when supplying a totally unknown word, the mere overlap with word-fragments that were seen during training – like `'mela'` or `'noma'` or `'xyz'` – allows a rough word-vector to be created. (Such vectors aren't great, but again usually better than nothing, though the lists of words in sets-of-results will still only include actually-present-during-training words.)

Comment: First and foremost thanks for the answer. Although, your provided example code didn't work as you are expecting.


`model.wv.most_similar(model.wv['melanoma'], topn=5)`

I will accept the answer once I will be able to dig a bit more into this. Please accept my apologies;

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the code to explicitly place the `model.wv['melanoma']` as one member of a list provided as the parameter `positive`, which should make it behave as originally described.

Answer (score 0):

As for including the search term in the most similar list, you can just add it manually at the beginning of the output list. Since the cosine similarity of a token to itself is `1`, it should always be the first token in the returned list.

As for including terms like `melanoma xyz` you can iterate over your corpus before training and join all such terms into one token using '_' - that is `melanoma_xyz`. Note that this way you will get different vectors for "melanoma" and `melanoma_xyz`. Hopefully they will be close to each other in the vector space.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because the probability of a word repeating itself around a word is almost zero. The corpus on which you train word2vec will most likely not have a string "melanoma melanoma" anywhere. After obtaining the embedded word vector for "melanoma", the vector that maximizes dot product with "melanoma" will be "melanoma" itself but such instances are not present in the input corpus.